# MS Access and Visual Basic - syntax error in insert into statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I get this error when I want to send data from form into table. This is Visual Basic code I wrote in MS Access:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Book(book_id,title,language_id,author_id,year_published,num_pages,publisher_id,num_copies)" & _
                      "Values (" & Null & ",'" & Me.txtTitle & "','" & Me.cbLanguage.Column(0) & "','" & Me.cbAuthor.Column(0) & "','" & Me.txtYearPublished & "','" & _
                      Me.txtNumPages & "','" & Me.cbPublisher.Column(0) & "','" & Me.txtNumCopies & "')"
End Sub
```

`book_id` is the primary key and auto-number.

Arrow indicating error appears on the 4th line of code.

Comment: Please update the original post. Is bbokID **Auto Number** type? Or a **Primary Key**, either case it should not be Null.

Comment: Yes, it is AutoNumber and primary key.

Comment: How about **author_ID**, **yearPublished**, **publisherID**, **numberCopies**.. you have included them as Text, are they actually text? Or Numbers?

Comment: Yes, they are all numbers. But how to convert them to numbers?

Comment: The & operator does the trick and converts your numbers to strings, no need to worry about it.

Comment: @LaszloTenki - If a field is declared as **Number**, and you Pass it a String value, I think there is a problem !

Answer (score 1):

Your main issues are because `Book_ID` is set to Auto Number type; it does not need to be passed, Access JET engine will take care of it for you. Then all your values are Numeric, but when you add a `'` to the variable you treat it as String/Text. So your code needs to change as,

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Book (title, language_id, author_id, year_published, " & _
                      "num_pages, publisher_id, num_copies) VALUES (" & Me.txtTitle & ", " & _
                      Me.cbLanguage.Column(0) & ", " & Me.cbAuthor.Column(0) & ", " & Me.txtYearPublished & _
                      ", " & Me.txtNumPages & ", " & Me.cbPublisher.Column(0) & ", " & Me.txtNumCopies & ")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't include book_id anywhere in the insert statement if it's PK and auto-incremented.